# missing Windows.Security.Credentials;

Tags: c#, asp.net

We want use Windows Credential Manager(Password Valut) in my asp.net application,In some blog we found that to use Password Vault Class in our application,

We need  to add Assembly file called  "Windows.Security.Credential.dll ", But we could not find that Assembly While adding a Reference to our solution,

Please guide me further,

1.Where to find the Windows.Security.Credential.dll ?
2.How to access the Password Vault?

Project Type: ASP.net application
SDK : Visual studio 2012

Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of proyect do you have? What version of VisualStudio are you using?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with it ? i think you might have chosen the wrong library for your asp.net project since windows.security.credentials is used for windows apps

Comment: Hello Experts,

We want use Windows Credential Manager(Password Valut) in my asp.net application,In some blog we found that to use Password Vault Class in our application,

We need  to add Assembly file called  "Windows.Security.Credential.dll ", But we could not find that Assembly While adding a Reference to our solution,

Please guide me further,

1.Where to find the Windows.Security.Credential.dll ?
2.How to access the Password Vault?

Project Type: ASP.net application
SDK : Visual studio 2012

Thanks in advance

Comment: The minimum OS-Version for this Assembly is Win 8. Have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227089)